# SQL - ORDER BY for multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I'm trying sort the results to get the results in such way that, 
if column value equals A then bring those result at the top by their due date,
if column value equals B then bring those result at the top by their due date,

if both A & B exists, then A should be the priority result then I should see B and then rest.

Here is the query I tried.

```
select ID,NAME,TYPE,due_date FROM (SELECT v.id, v.name, b.task_type,a.due_date  FROM tabe1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id
 UNION ALL 
//similar select statement with where condition

order by due_date)
order by case when type='ABC' then 1 else 2 end,
         case when type='XYZ' then 1 else 2 end;
```

for what I tried, I get the correct result at top for the first condition by due date and I also get result for second condition but there is **no** order for due date

**Sample Result**

```
ID     | Name    | Type    | due_date
------ | ------- | ------- | ------------
123    | test1   | ABC     | 10-May-2018
456    | test2   | ABC     | 15-AUG-2019
789    | test3   | ABC     | 29-JAN-2020
098    | test4   | XYZ     | 13-JUN-2019
876    | test5   | XYZ     | 12-JAN-2018
```

I was expecting the last two rows should be sorted by due date. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm not clear if this is what you want, but try `order by case type when 'ABC' then 1 when 'XYZ' then 2 else 3 end asc, due_date desc`

Comment: @kfinity Thanks. you suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully functional SQL. Use the CASE WHEN to set order base on the type content.

```
SELECT      id, name, type, due_date
FROM        (
                SELECT      v.id, v.name, b.task_type AS type, a.due_date
                FROM        tabe1 AS a1 JOIN table2 AS b1 on a1.id=b1.id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT      v.id, v.name, b.task_type AS type, a.due_date
                FROM        tabe1 AS a2 JOIN table2 AS b2 on a2.id=b2.id
            ) AS tbl
ORDER BY    CASE WHEN type='ABC' THEN 1 WHEN type='XYZ' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
            , tbl.due_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The only order of the outer query is significant for final order

```
select ID,NAME,TYPE,due_date 
FROM (SELECT v.id, v.name, b.task_type,a.due_date  
        FROM tabe1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id
       UNION ALL 
       //similar select statement with where condition
) as A
order by case when A.type='ABC' then 1 else 2 end,
         case when A.type='XYZ' then 1 else 2 end, A.due_date;
```